# rewrite rule for case sensitive directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm looking into setting up a re-write to ignore the case of the directory name of the URL.

For example, I have

```
example.com/TestDirectory
```

I want to ignore the case so the URL will still direct to

```
example.com/testdirectory
```

Here is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
# rewrite rules for example.com/TestDirectory
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com\TestDirectory [NC]
RewriteRule $ http://www.example.ccom/testdirectory/
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: http_host does not contain directories.  It's a hostname, not a full URL.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement a canonical redirect to the correctly cased directory (in this case, all lowercase) you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testdirectory
RewriteRule ^testdirectory /testdirectory/ [NC,R,L]
```

The `NC` (`nocase`) flag on the `RewriteRule` ensures that it would match `TestDirectory` or `TESTDIRECTORY` etc. and the `RewriteCond` directive prevents a redirect loop by checking that we are not already at `testdirectory` via a case-sensitive match.

However, this only redirects to the directory. Any file after the directory name is lost. In order to redirect `/TestDirectory/<whatever>` to `/testdirectory/<whatever>` then try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testdirectory
RewriteRule ^testdirectory/?(.*) /testdirectory/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Change the `R` flag to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only after you have checked that it is working OK.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com\TestDirectory [NC]
> ```

Note that the `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the requested hostname. There is no URL-path information. If you need to check the host as well (if you have multiple domains) then include an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
```

(This assumes the domain has already been canonicalised to include the www subdomain.)